# After removing a line "RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type PlotCurveItem has been deleted" pops up

Tags: python, pyqt, garbage-collection, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I want to plot some data stored in a list of numpy arrays and be able to click on a plotted line.
After clicking a line that line needs to be removed from my data and everything else cleared and redrawn.

Just removing the line from the plot `pw.getPlotItem().removeItem(curve)` is not an option, sometimes I need to clear everything.

So the question is how to avoid the annoying `RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type PlotCurveItem has been deleted` error? Here is the minimum example of what I am talking about.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = pg.mkQApp()
mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
mw.resize(800, 800)
cw = QtGui.QWidget()
mw.setCentralWidget(cw)
l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
cw.setLayout(l)

pw = pg.PlotWidget()
l.addWidget(pw)
mw.show()

lines = [np.random.normal(size=5) for _ in range(5)]
curves_list = []


def clicked(curve):
    idx = pw.getPlotItem().items.index(curve)
    del lines[idx]
    draw()

    # this is not an option
    # pw.getPlotItem().removeItem(curve)


def draw():
    pw.clear()
    curves_list.clear()
    for line in lines:
        curve = pw.plot(line)
        curve.curve.setClickable(True)
        curve.sigClicked.connect(clicked)
        curves_list.append(curve)


draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is synchronization since it seems that an instant after the deletion, another code is executed that uses the deleted items, therefore it launches that warning. The solution is to give it a little delay with `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)`:

```py
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
```

```py
def clicked(curve):
    def on_timeout():
        curves_list.remove(curve)
        pw.removeItem(curve)
        draw()

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, on_timeout)
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine. Maybe you also know how to make it so it's easier to click on a line without making the line thicker?

Comment: @VitaminC use `curve.curve.setClickable(True, width=20)`